# Convert object to date when it starts from 1

Tags: angular, typescript, date, datepicker, bootstrap-4

I have added the `angular bootstrap datepicker` component into my app and when I choose the date I receive an object which looks like: `{year: 1993, month: 8, day: 9}` and I'd like to convert it to a `Date` object. Everything goes quite good but after conversion to Date, the whole date is moved: `1993-09-08T22:00:00.000Z`. Do you know any tricks by which date conversion will still have the same date?

I already investigated that the problem occured because of the start date number. In angular bootstrap it starts from 1 but in a date object it starts from 0.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-12 mb-3 form-group">
    <label for="dateOfBirth">Data urodzenia</label>

    <input class="form-control"
        placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" id="dateOfBirth" 
        formControlName="dateOfBirth"
        name="dp"
        ngbDatepicker
        #d="ngbDatepicker"
        (click)="d.toggle()" 
        [minDate]="fromDate"
        [maxDate]="toDate">

    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
    </span>

    <ngb-alert [type]="'danger'"
        [dismissible]="false" 
        class="form-alert"
        *ngIf="envelopeCreationFrom.controls.dateOfBirth.touched && 
        envelopeCreationFrom.controls.dateOfBirth.errors?.required">
        Error
    </ngb-alert>
</div>
```

Typescript:

```
 console.log(dateOfBirth);
 console.log(new Date(dateOfBirth['year'], dateOfBirth['month'], dateOfBirth['day']));
 console.log(new Date(dateOfBirth['year'], dateOfBirth['month'], dateOfBirth['day']).toISOString());
 console.log(new Date(dateOfBirth['year'], dateOfBirth['month'], dateOfBirth['day']).toDateString());
```

Comment: why you don't just add 1 ? dateOfBirth['month'] + 1 instead of dateOfBirth['month']

Comment: because it seems to me as hack which I would like to omit

Comment: you can do this if you prefer new Date(dateOfBirth.year+'-'+dateOfBirth.month+'-'+dateOfBirth.day) or const {year,month,day} = dateOfBirth;
new Date(year+'-'+month+'-'+day)

Comment: Did you provide a date adapter?

Comment: @JanTestowy, if you want to mannage the dates as JavaScript Date, you can use as provider: `providers: [{provide: NgbDateAdapter, useClass: NgbDateNativeAdapter}]`, see the example in the docs:https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples#adapter. Else, take account that ng-datepicker months begans with 1 (1=January) and Date object, months begans with 0 (0=January). futhermore, it's util defining date as `new Date(dateOfBirth.year,dateOfBirth.month-1,dateOfBirth.day,12)`. See the "12" to avoid problems with the GTM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using moment.js if your cases with dates will include any kind of calculation or date formatting etc.

You need to install moment first.

```
npm install moment --save
```

Just import in the component where you need it.

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

Comment: Can you give an example how to use it?

Comment: @JanTestowy, for example: moment().year(dateOfBirth['year']).date(dateOfBirth['day']).month(dateOfBirth['month'] - 1)